# Android - Uploading new APK with updated permissions to a published app

Tags: android, google-play

So I'm having trouble uploading a new APK to the play store with billing enabled.

Currently I have a published app that is paid and I want to change it to a subscription app such that the users get a yearly subscription and hence latest data to the app.

Now my issue is that the developer console will not let me upload a draft APK with the permissions for billing enabled. I log into the dev console, go to APK, change from simple to advanced mode, save my new APK as a draft and once uploaded I get the following error:

```
This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):

All devices that might receive version 1 would receive version 2.

Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario, the device will receive the APK with the higher version code.
```

I updated the Version code and the version number to be one higher than the current as well as different combinations of upping only one of the two values with still no success.

The app is being signed with the same keystore.

Thanks,
DMan

Comment: This will only come if you activate the second apk. You do not need to activate to upload as a draft. Do not activate it.

Comment: @RaghavSood I don't quite understand what you mean by activate. In no steps did I select "Activate" nor click anything to activate. I merely uploaded the new APK as a draft (button said "Save Draft") in the developer console. Once the draft was uploaded the error occurred. There is currently an active apk for the published app (which I'd prefer not to take out of published state until my new version is ready).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Figured out what this actually means now. Basically it was just telling me that I need to archive the current apk in order to actually publish the new apk. The new apk was successfully added as a draft. This message was just worded a little awkwardly and actually means that in order to publish version 2 version 1 must be archived NOT that there was anything wrong with the saved draft I performed.

Thanks,
Dman

Comment: Amazingly complex way of saying 'click on archive before you can publish' :-)

Comment: Hi Dman, I'm encountering a similar situation, but I can't find "archive" or "deactivate", only "delete". I can't delete the old APK since it has my expansion file. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @SirKnigget Not sure if you still need a hand on this, but I just took a look and it seems that if you click "Switch to Advanced Mode" in the top right hand corner of your developer console. It should show a deactivate button beside the currently published APK while in your list of APKs. Now as for what this will do exactly, I am unsure as I am not in a position to try it out, but do some research on that and maybe it will turn out to help you. Thanks, Dman

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all you have to do is to disable the old aplication, after that a the Publish botton will be available to push on the top left area so your new APK will be published

Answer (score 2):

Did you disable your first version? By default, after uploading in advanced mode, both your first and 2nd version are activated. Looks to me like it's just saying that you've got 2 APKs active, that will reach the same devices thus one of the 2 is useless.

Comment: In disabling my first version does that make it unavailable to users for download? I just want to be able to add in-app purchasing which according to google documentation doesn't require the activation (which I'm guessing means publishing) of the app. After uploading, I can archive the original version or delete the new draft I uploaded. So how do I deactivate my draft?

Comment: Don't quite follow you here. 
What do you want to achieve with the draft? Do you want people to be able to download it? 
Enabling the new one, and disabling the old version, will present people (eventually) with an update of your app and any new downloaders will instantly get the newest version.

Comment: Basically I want my current version still available while I test the new version with in-app purchasing. The current version does not have billing permissions as that wasn't the initial intent. The new APK does so I need that uploaded as a draft such that I can add items, whilst not interrupting new users from getting the version that is currently published.

Comment: Oke sorry, have no experience with in-app payments and testing it ;) Seems like its simply a case Google did not think about. Since its just for testing, you could add some options into your manifest which will filter out some devices. Like this, the 2nd version would reach a different array of devices, and thus be accepted by Google Play as a 2nd APK. Once you tested it successfully, you can change the filter options back and override your first version.

Comment: No need to apologize. Tried this by adding some devices to the unsupported list and then uploading the apk but that didnt clear it up. Seems like the supported list is per package not per apk.

Comment: What exactly did you do to change the supported list?

Comment: I just changed some of the devices that are supported to unsupported (just devices that have relatively low percentage in android share).