# Google Play Uploading new APK file

Tags: android, version, apk, publish

I uploaded an APK for alpha which is version 1.0 and published as alpha. I made some changes in application and want to change the previous apk but it says 1.0 already exists. I tried to upload 1.0.1 but it says the same. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried deactivating V1.0 first?

Comment: yes, but then it says "at least one apk must be active"

Comment: I want to publish my app as 1.0 :/ not 2.0

Comment: You can't upload the same version? That's the point of versioning. Change it to V1.0.0.0.0.1 if you like... You may need to archive the current version first - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15279048/1256219

Comment: They seem to be expecting you choose <1.0 as the version for the alpha (e.g. 0.1)

Comment: I uploaded version 1 for alpha. I now tried uploading even v2.0 but it says the same. I'm exporting via unity3d, I think there is a problem with unity in versioning.

Comment: This question appears to be off topic as it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

old manifist file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.urlconnectionclass"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >
```

new manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.urlconnectionclass"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1.0" >
```

always increse the value of   versioncode and versionname while uploding apk of same production

Answer (score 1):

Two important rules from Google:

1. 

> The Version Code needs to be greater than that current version. [Learn more about versioning your applications.](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)
>   
>   Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.package.name"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.1">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

2. 

> The updated APK needs to be signed with the same signature as the
>   current version.
>   
>   All rules and requirements: [Update your apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en)

Comment: I am glad to help you. Can you give me positive vote.

Answer (score 0):

You change version in android manifest?