# Max API level in Play Store stuck at 19

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded an APK to the app store, it's targeting lollipop, but on Google Play Store it says "API levels 14-19".
I can't seem to figure out why the max sdk level is stuck at 19.

compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "be.appwise.dentir"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

Comment: try to remove targetSDK field.

Comment: Just tried it, no luck.

Comment: That is same as my problem, but it had happen for a long time ago, so I can't remember the right way to fix :(

Comment: try this topic @TomCB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453702/android-configuration-cannot-be-published-while-uploading-apk-to-play-store?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Change your version code and versionName to

```
versionCode 2
versionName "1.1"
```

and then try upadting your app on the google playstore

Comment: TomCB do not want to update his app. He needs solution.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for the input, which brought me to the solution:
search in the whole project for maxSdk. I found it, is was defined by one of my used libraries, so I deleted it for now. Now I can target +14.